# Unexpected error while launching app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am new to java and i started to code an app for Android, but i have an error, i think the problem is about the intent filter, but i'm really not sure.. i dont understand any single thing here. How i could perform my level ? Is my code a good point of start ?

Error message:

```
     $ adb shell am start -n "test.beta1/test.beta1.MainActivity" -a 
       android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
       Unexpected error while executing: am start -n 
       "test.beta1/test.beta1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c 
       android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
       Error while Launching activity
```

Main activity code (updated) :

```
   package test.beta1;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.media.Image;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   View.OnClickListener{
   private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE  = 1;
   ImageView imageToUpload;
   Button bUploadImage;


  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     imageToUpload  =  (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
     bUploadImage  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.etUploadName);
     imageToUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
     bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.imageToUpload:
           Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
         MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
          break;
      case R.id.bUploadImage:

          break;

  }
}

 @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) 
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != 
       null){
        Uri selectedImage  = data.getData();
        imageToUpload.setImageURI(selectedImage);

       }
      }
  }
```

Activity_main.xml code :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageToUpload"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUploadName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bUploadImage"
        android:text="Upload Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please, Can you explain how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You should have a stack trace in the ADB logs when trying to run it. can you provide the log?

Comment: event log :15/10/17
12:50 AM Gradle sync completed
1:19 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
1:19 AM Gradle build finished with 4 error(s) in 5s 362ms
1:20 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
1:20 AM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 2s 261ms
1:26 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
1:26 AM Gradle build finished in 1s285ms
1:27 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
1:27 AM Gradle build finished in 4s424ms
1:28 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
1:28 AM Gradle build finished in 1s879ms
1:29 AM Session 'app': Error Launching activity

Comment: i've added the gradle console in the post(edited it)

Comment: I get the apk file while running but after i open ,it closes after 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source of the problems from this error:

`/Users/abhinanda/Desktop/Beta1/app/src/main/java/test/beta1/MainActivity.java:16: error: variable bDownloadedImage is already defined in class MainActivity Button bUploadImage, bDownloadedImage; ^`

`/Users/abhinanda/Desktop/Beta1/app/src/main/java/test/beta1/MainActivity.java:28: error: incompatible types: Button cannot be converted to ImageView bDownloadedImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.etDownloadName); ^ 2 errors`

First,  you define **bDownloadedImage** more than one.
Second,  your are trying to cast Button to ImageView which is an error.

Check your layout.

Comment: for now i removed the downloaded image.I just want the upload image to work.andi didnot understand the second problem u sorted out.i have added my activity_main.xml code and my updated Main_activity.java in the post above(edited).Please help asap

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate, you are casting wrong id to bUploadImage. The id you are casting R.id.etUploadName is a Textview

Comment: so i should cast the button?or imageview?

Comment: Just change this line "bUploadImage  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.etUploadName);" in your oncreate to "bUploadImage  = (Button) findViewById(R.id. bUploadImage);" Upvote if the issue is fixed